# How to post to facebook from iPhone using publish.stream without the Facebook dialog method

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk

I would simply like to use publish.stream to post to Facebook from an iPhone app but without using the UIWebview that pops up when you call the Facebook object's  dialog method. How do I do this?

Comment: I never encountered a UIWebView. 
Are you using the new api or the old one?

Comment: I believe its the new one. The relevant code is                       [fb dialog: @"stream.publish"
 andParams: params
        andDelegate:self];  where 'fb' is a Facebook object.

Answer (score 2):

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON alloc] init];     NSDictionary *attchmentDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                              @"Foobar",@"name",
                              nil];     NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attchmentDic];   NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Bla-bla",@"message",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];
        [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"stream.publish"

                       andParams:params 
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                     andDelegate:self];     [jsonWriter release];
```